# Get page header and footer preview in backend

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I have created a TYPO3 plugin to add new content columns to tt_content.

I need the header and footer content for my preview page in the backend. Once i get the header and footer I can show my contents in between this.
I want to insert some edit features in the content area. that is why I need the html rendered output to a php variable.

I am using *templavoila*.

I tried this - but got an error:

```
$this->cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$conf = array('userFunc' => 'tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page');
$content = $this->cObj->USER($conf);
```

> #1316104317: The default controller for extension "myplugin" and plugin "ContentRenderer" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 you have? Bcoz of If you are working in 6.2 up then "t3lib_div" will not work coz "t3lib" was removed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this TypoScript :

```
10 = USER
10 { 
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
    pluginName = Pi1
    extensionName = EXTNAME
    controller = CONTROLLERNAME
    action = ACTION
}
```

Just replace `EXTNAME`, `CONTROLLERNAME`, `ACTION`.